# Determine programmatically screens geometry in a multi-desktop environment with Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a screenshotting app (a bit like puush) using Qt 4.8, and I am having troubles with multiple screens setups, especially when the main monitor (with coordinates `(0,0)`) is not the leftmost one.

Warning : this is NOT a duplicate of this question : [Capture multiple screens desktop image using Qt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966429/capture-multiple-screens-desktop-image-using-qt4), as it solved partially the problem.

The first original code was the following, which worked fine until you had more than one monitor, as only the main one would be captured.

```
QPixmap shot = QPixmap::grabWindow (QApplication::desktop->winId ());
```

Result:

[image]

Then the thread linked previously headed me towards specifying the full desktop width and height :

```
QDesktopWidget *desktop = QApplication::desktop ();
QPixmap shot = QPixmap::grabWindow (desktop->winId (), 0, 0, desktop->width(), desktop->height());
```

But because my second monitor is on the left, its `x` coordinates are in the negative, resulting in the following screenshot :

[image]

The second monitor is 1680px wide, so feeding `-1680` to the second argument of `grabWindow` made a proper screenshot :

[image]

So here is the question : how can I determine programmatically this `-1680` value to feed to Qt ? This corresponds to the minimal `x` coordinate allowed on the screen.

Maybe moving the mouse to something like -100000px then grabbing back its coordinates would work, but it seems a bit too "hackish" to me (and might cause issues in applications grabbing the mouse, eg. games). A portable Qt solution would be the best, but OS specific code is fine too, I have not tested my code under X11 or a muli-screen Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [access each screen information](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html#screenCount-prop) inside the `QDesktopWidget` widget you are using and [compute](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qrect.html#united) the overall rectangle for the snapshot.

```
int screens = desktop->screenCount();
QRect wholeDisplayGeometry;
for (int i = 0; i < screens; ++i) {
     QRect screenRect = desktop->screen(i)->geometry();
     wholeDisplayGeometry = wholeDisplayGeometry.united(screenRect); //union
}
```

Now you can take the shot using the rectangle information:

```
QPixmap shot = QPixmap::grabWindow (
    desktop->winId (), 
    wholeDisplayGeometry.x(), 
    wholeDisplayGeometry.y(), 
    wholeDisplayGeometry.width(), 
    wholeDisplayGeometry.height()
);
```