# QGuiApplication::primaryScreen() with multiple screens on mac

Tags: qt

I want to capture a screenshot in Qt:

```
originalPixmap = QPixmap();
    QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
    if (screen) {
        originalPixmap = screen->grabWindow(0);
    }
```

That works usually fine. When I have a second monitor connected on a Mac, though, `grabWindow()` will return one image that shows both displays. Is there a way to just capture the screens individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no such way. You have to split up the pixmap yourself, based on the geometry of each screen. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25604167/1329652) for details of determining the geometry.